# Prove/disprove that the matrix $AB+BA=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be matrices of an order $5\times 5$ such that:
$$AB+BA=0$$

Prove/disprove: at least one of the two matrices is not invertible.

I wanna say I tried various ways before I posted here but I have no clue where to begin from.

Any chance I get the right approach of solving this?
The only thing I know is that $AB+BA=0$, how can that help me?

Thanks a lot, I really need this help.

Comment: If $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, what is $det(-M)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $\det(-BA)=(-1)^5\det(BA)=-\det(A)\det(B)$

Comment: Can you please explain why $det(-BA)=(-1)^5det(BA)$?

Comment: @FigureItOut The determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix is an $n$-linear function of its columns. When multiplying a matrix by $-1$, you multiply each of its columns by $-1$.

Comment: @FigureItOut or, if you prefer, note that
$$
\det(-BA) = \det(-IBA) = \det(-I) \det(BA)
$$

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false. Counterexample: $A=B=I_5$ over $GF(2)$ (in which $1+1=0$).

The statement is true, however, when the underlying field is of characteristic $\ne2$. In particular, it's true if you are talking about real or complex matrices. See the other answers for various proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ is invertible; then
$$
B=A^{-1}(-B)A
$$
so $B$ and $-B$ have the same eigenvalues (with the same algebraic multiplicity).

Comment: How do you know that $B=A^{-1}(-B)A$? I just don't understand how you can say that, can you please clarify? :)

Comment: @FigureItOut $AB=(-B)A$; then multiply on the left by $A^{-1}$ (which we assumed to exist).